# Should image DPI be 72pixels/inch in 2018?

Tags: image, imagemagick, dpi, ppi

Some DPI stats first:

Mack Book Pro 13.3" has **227 DPI**(2560x1600px/13.3 inches).

iPhone 6s has **326 DPI**(750x1334px/4.7 inches).

Sony Xperia Z tablet has **224 DPI**(1920x1200px/10.10 inches).

However when I save JPEG image for web it has **72 DPI** and the image looks good only if I set container resolution 2 times lower then the image resolution.

For example,

```
<img src="200x200px_72dpi_image.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
```

produces good results for retina displays(iPhone 6s, Mac Book Pro 13.3", etc.) and

```
<img src="100x100px_72dpi_image.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
```

produces bad results.

What can I do with that in 2018? Should 300 DPI image be used for web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple figured they would have an issue with this topic, and released several guidelines / suggestions how to handle it.

- [About Proper Image Delivery on the Web](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Serving Images Efficiently to Displays of Varying Pixel Density](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012449-CH3-SW1)

It all boils down to websites serving `2x` images *IF* the client browser *CAN* support it -- else default back down to the 72 DPI standard.

> Should image DPI be 72pixels/inch in 2018?

Yes. Devices that support higher resolution are relatively recent, and have yet to reach 100% market saturation.

> Should 300 DPI image be used for web?

300 DPI might be overkill. Images of that resolution would have very large file sizes, and users might be more put-off from longer load times than slightly pixelated images. You'll need to design a reasonable balance that is inline with your business requirements.

> What can I do with that in 2018?

My two cents...

- Explore other formats than JPEG. Explore SVG for line-art graphics. [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) is also worth exploring for photos.
- Default to 72dpi, and opt-in to higher DPI. With media queries, and many poplar modern CSS/JS frameworks, it takes very little effort for the device to load `2x` resource over low-res defaults. True, you'll need to render the same image assets in different resolutions, but that can be automated.
- Time. Even in 2018, this stuff is still changing, and vendors are competing in this HDR space. Expect `-webkit`, `-moz` & `-ms` prefixes until a standard is reached (if not all ready).